# No such column 'CreatedDate' on Custom_Object__Share

Tags: soql, custom-object, query, sharing

I was trying to query **Custom_Object__Share**  `SELECT Id, ParentId,UserOrGroupId, AccessLevel, RowCause from Custom_Object__Share where  CreatedDate > 2016-08-25T00:25:43Z`

I am getting an error no such column `CreatedDate` not sure why, any inputs/help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Share Records do not have the createdDate field .

You can filter all the records using createdDate and then filter with ParentId .

```
map<Id,Credit_Applicant__c> maprecords = new map<Id,Credit_Applicant__c>([Select Id from Credit_Applicant__c where CreatedDate > 2016-08-25T00:25:43Z];
```

then run a query on share table

```
SELECT Id, ParentId,UserOrGroupId, AccessLevel, RowCause from Credit_Applicant__Share where  ParentId IN : maprecords.keyset();
```

Comment: Mohit, can I not just use lastModifiedDate? Just asking! Will there be any issues doing so? Instead of making things complicated as you suggested?

Comment: Sure you can use lastModifiedDate but its not true createdDate .It might resemble createdDate if share records are not modified

Comment: LOL! Thanks! I was more interested in why CreatedDate is not available on Share object and not on how to get around of the error I got! Cause learning that can reveal some important salesforce implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to filter on the Credit Applicant record's created date (and not the share record's created date)...

Add 'Parent.' to the criteria

```
SELECT Id, ParentId,UserOrGroupId, AccessLevel, RowCause FROM Credit_Applicant__Share WHERE Parent.CreatedDate > 2016-08-25T00:25:43Z
```

Comment: Not sure what are you referring too vorno, but I want Share record's createddate.

Comment: Share records do not record the Created Date, only the parent (data) record has Created Date. There is a Last Modified Date field on the share object, but that's about it.

Comment: That is what I commented on Mohits answer as well. But I am more interested in learning why salesforce wouldn't give createddate on share record ?